# redirect break if URL have space

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have hosted a site(using wordpress), and theres an option for me and my team to upload file and share with any team. The problem is, the file is accessible with everyone on the net. It is listed if everyone search on google.

So i private the folder using htaccess. which i refer from here : [Link](http://www.idowebdesign.ca/wordpress/password-protect-wordpress-attachments/).

basically here are the code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /wp-login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And it did work.but if my files have space in it, examples

> this attachment here.pdf

it will not work.it will redirect to my default page.i have googled areound for broken-redirect-with-space-%20-htaccess. but didnt find any. help :(

Answer (score 0):

Try including a `B` flag in this rule:

```
RewriteRule . /wp-login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,B]
```

to ensure that the query string gets encoded properly.